# Calculate a Matrix of a LT given some vectors transforms

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

If $M \begin{bmatrix}1\\2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}3\\1\end{bmatrix}$ and $M \begin{bmatrix}-2\\1\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2\\1\end{bmatrix}$, Then $M = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix}^{-1}$.

How can I calculate the matrix M? This is an answer of an exercise, but it doesn't show the step-by-step solution.

Comment: What do you mean by "how can I assess"? Do you know how to find the inverse of a matrix? What about multiplying matrices?

Comment: Hint: Take any linear combination of the inputs and try to force something nice.

Comment: @CalvinLin I know how to find the inverse of a matrix. I Know That if multiply by $M^{-1}$ on both sides, I have the domain vectors. I just don't know why M is given by a compose of linear transformations. I can't get this result.

Comment: Do you understand that $M \begin{bmatrix}-2 & 1\\ 1 & 2\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}2 & 3\\ 1 & 1\end{bmatrix}$?

Comment: @CalvinLin Actually, don't. But with this information, now it's easy to get the answer. Thank you, my friend!

Answer (score 0):

The reasoning from the solution guide was probably as follows: $M \begin{pmatrix}-2\\1 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and
$M \begin{pmatrix}1\\2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$

$$\implies M\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\1&2 \end{pmatrix} = \begin{pmatrix}2&3\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$$
$$\implies M=\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}
\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\1&2 \end{pmatrix}^{-1}.$$

The jump to the second line is the part that likely felt tricky. You can convince yourself by writing down the matrix multiplication by hand. Or alternatively, if you are familiar with abstract linear maps, you can think of $M$ as the linear transformation that maps $\begin{pmatrix}-2\\1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}2\\1 \end{pmatrix}$ and
$ \begin{pmatrix}1\\2 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}3\\1 \end{pmatrix}$; then the composition of of linear maps $M\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$ will map $$e_1\mapsto \begin{pmatrix}-2\\1 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}2\\1 \end{pmatrix} and $$
$$e_2\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}1\\2 \end{pmatrix} \mapsto \begin{pmatrix}3\\1 \end{pmatrix}.$$ Therefore, the composition of linear maps $M\begin{pmatrix}-2&1\\1&2\end{pmatrix}$ is equivalent to the linear map $\begin{pmatrix}2&3\\ 1&1\end{pmatrix}$.